# Can't install PyQt5 using pip

Tags: python, pyqt, pip, pyqt5

I have tried to install PyQt5 using

```
pip install PyQt5
```

and

```
sudo -H pip install PyQt5
```

both of them give me the errors

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt5
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

My python version is: Python 2.7.15rc1

---

I have already installed python3-pip and tried to install PyQt5 using

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

My python3 version is: Python3.6.7.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: In a few months Python2 will be deprecated so many libraries have already decided not to support Python2, and one of those libraries is PyQt5 as indicated by the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5/): *Wheels are provided for Python v3.5 and later for 64-bit Linux, macOS and 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.* So it is advisable that you use Python3 if you are learning or if you are going to develop an application: `pip3 install PyQt5`

Comment: find it strange that pip3 use python2: `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: I thought that too. I was thinking of uninstalling Python2 but found in another post that is not a good idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
```

Comment: Thank you! this works. Can you explain this command a little more?

Comment: It tells the terminal to run a Python module named pip with the commands `install PyQt5`. `Python3` explicitly directs which version to use, which is important when you have several installed.

Comment: -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Answer (score 24):

You need to upgrade your pip

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Then do a fresh install

```
pip install PyQt5
```

or

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Comment: This is one useful tip that I always have to remind myself.

Comment: This was the answer for me.

Comment: didn't work for me on Linux

Answer (score 6):

I know it is a bit late to answer.
In PyCharm, even upgraded pip gives error in this package.
Downgraded the PyQt5 version to 5.12.2 works fine.
Use,

```
pip install PyQt5==5.12.2 
pip install PyQtWebEngine==5.12
```

Or,

```
pip3 install PyQt5==5.12.2
pip3 install PyQtWebEngine==5.12
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: This worked for me. But why do you need to install PyQtWebEngine==5.12?

Answer (score 0):

You can run command

```
   pip3 install PyQt5
```

or for Python 2 you can manually install from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5

Comment: I have edited my post, I still get an error with that command

Comment: Try the second variant.